# Why do I have to use both rest parameter and spread operator in the below example?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```js
function f(...y){
      y.forEach(v => {
        console.log("111");
        console.log(v);
      });
    }

var z=["a","b","c","d","e","f"];

f(z);
```

Expected output:

```
"111"
"a"
"111"
"b"
"111"
"c"
"111"
"d"
"111"
"e"
"111"
"f"
```

Actual output:

```
"111"
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

Only when I change the line `f(z)` to `f(...z)` I get the expected output. I am new to ECMAScript 2015. Please tell me what am I missing here.

Comment: Rest parameter is not necessary to return expected result, you can use `function f(y){}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`f(z)` means only one argument (in this case, an array) is passed to the method, while `f(...z)` means, the values in array are passed as parameter to the function.

Read More :

1. [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)
2. [Rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

```js
function f(...y){
      console.log(y.length);
    }

var z=["a","b","c","d","e","f"];
f(z);
f(...z);
```

Comment: This makes it pretty clear. So when I call using `f(z)` what happens is the parameter `z` as the whole array becomes the first element of the array argument `...y`. I'll wait for some more time to see if others have any more additional points. I will then go ahead and accept this answer later. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, when you pass `z`, `...y` treats it as a single param. while `...z` expands `z` and `...y` gets 6 params

Comment: My two cents: you don't need to spread anything for the desired output. You can just do `var z=["a","b","c","d","e","f"];

(z).forEach(letter=> {
        console.log("111");
        console.log(letter);
      });`